# How to send frames using User Datagram Protocol (UDP)

Tags: c#

I have a device which i need to communicate to via host computer using C# and exchange frames between the device and host computer which are connected via Ethernet cable.The device has a port and ip which can be connected to.The following is sample code of frames communication between sender and receiver.
I have little knowledge in C# and i would like some help on how to establish the communication below using UDP  protocol suite.Thanks

```
//Grab the data of the device
    private byte[] Fetch_FrameID(bool bHostToDevice)    //true:Host to Device false: Device to Host
    {
        return bHostToDevice ? new byte[] { 0x8F, 0xE1 } : new byte[] { 0x2D, 0x7A };
    }

    //Grab the Frame Sequence Number
    private byte[] Fetch_FrameSequenceNumber(int iNumber)
    {
        return new byte[] { (byte)(iNumber & 0xFF), (byte)((iNumber >> 8) & 0xFF) };
    }

    //Grab the device status
    private byte[] Fetch_HostToDeviceCommand(int iStatus)   //status:0:Active 1:Sync 2:Request
    {
        switch (iStatus)
        {
            case 0: return new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00 };     //Active
            case 1: return new byte[] { 0x11, 0x00 };     //Sync
            case 2: return new byte[] { 0x21, 0x00 };     //Request 
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    //Fetch Data Length
    private byte[] Fetch_DataLen(byte[] dataArray)
    {
        int iLength = dataArray == null ? 0 : dataArray.Length;
        return new byte[] { (byte)(iLength & 0xFF), (byte)((iLength >> 8) & 0xFF) };
    }

    //Fetch Data Check  Sum
    private byte[] Fetch_DataCheckSum(byte[] dataArray)
    {
        int iSum = 0;
        if (dataArray != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
            {
                iSum += (int)dataArray[i];
            }
        }
        iSum += Convert.ToInt32("0xAA55", 16);
        return new byte[] { (byte)(iSum & 0xFF), (byte)((iSum >> 8) & 0xFF) };
    }


    private byte[] Fetc_SendHeaderInfo(int iStatus, int iNumber, byte[] dataArray)  //status:0:Active 1:Sync 2:Request
    {
        List<byte> result = new List<byte>();//TOTAL 12Bytes, each 2bytes
        result.AddRange(Fetch_FrameID(true));//Grab FrameID
        result.AddRange(Fetch_FrameSequenceNumber(iNumber));//Grab the FSN
        result.AddRange(Fetch_HostToDeviceCommand(iStatus));//Grab host to device command
        result.AddRange(Fetch_DataLen(dataArray));//Grab the data Length
        result.AddRange(Fetch_DataCheckSum(dataArray)); //Grab the data Check sum
        result.AddRange(Fetch_DataCheckSum(result.ToArray())); //Grab the headdata Check sum
        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: UDP and TCP are similar but not the same.  TCP is reliable which means every message is acknowledged while UDP doesn't acknowledge.  UDP also has a multicast mode that TCP doesn't have.  When you make a connection both ends need to be using the same mode.  You cannot mix modes.

Comment: _"UDP as part of TCP/IP"_ That's not right. You can go for UDP _or_ TCP. Mutually exclusive. Haven't heard of "UDP over TCP".

Comment: In my case i wanted to use UDP protocol

Comment: How about [UdpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: thanks for the correction above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP and TCP are different protocols, in order to send UDP packets using .NET C# I suggest using `UdpClient`, here is a sample code for sending if that helps :

```
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(ip, port);

try{
    udpClient.Send(bytesToSend, bytesToSendLength);
}
catch ( Exception e ){
    Console.WriteLine( e.ToString());
}
```

as for receiving you can use  `UdpClient.Receive`

Here is [Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08h8s12k(v=vs.110).aspx) & [Receive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation on MSDN